# Como colorear las horas laborables con fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Estimados, tengo un gran problema. Estoy haciendo un sistema de reserva de horas, por ende estoy usando `fullcalendar.io` una librería bastante completa.

Lo que necesito hacer es:
Como colorear de un color verde claro o verde transparente, determinadas horas de la semana de manera periódica. Como para demostrar que esas horas se encuentran disponibles.

Para eso agregué un evento pero en fullcalendar no soporta eventos periódicos (que se repita todos los lunes). Necesito solo colorear las horas disponibles con una hora de inicio, fin y el día de la semana.

Es posible hacer eso?

```
$('#calendario').fullCalendar({
      defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
      allDaySlot: false,
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        //alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());
        $("#hora_seleccionada").html(date.format("MM/DD/YYYY, h:mm:ss"));

      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una nueva forma a esta solución:
Si bien businessHours funciona tuve otro problema que era agregar un arreglo de businessHours y además funciona de manera contraría como mi problema estaba estipulado.

Encontré este problema en Stack Overflow principal:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30977505/how-to-add-multiple-business-hours-in-fullcalendar

Los que hice fue agregar un evento de color verde claro con opacidad:

```
events: [
    {
        start: '00:00:00+02:00',
        end: '08:00:00+02:00',
        color: 'green',
        rendering: 'background',
        dow: [1,2,3,4,5]
    },

    {
        start: '16:00:00+02:00',
        end: '24:00:00+02:00',
        color: 'green',
        rendering: 'background',
        dow: [1,2,3,4,5]
    },

    {
        start: '00:00:00+02:00',
        end: '8:00:00+02:00',
        color: 'green',
        rendering: 'background',
        dow: [6]
    },

    {
        start: '12:00:00+02:00',
        end: '24:00:00+02:00',
        color: 'green',
        rendering: 'background',
        dow: [6]
    }
]
```

Gracias @rnrneverdies por aclararme de dudas

Answer (score 5):

Fullcalendar tiene incorporada una función similar, pero funciona al revés de lo que tu quieres. Es decir que colorea las horas no laborables.

La propiedad [businessHours](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/businessHours/) establece el rango horario y días de semana que se desea resaltar de forma diferente (horas no laborables).

Esto no crea *eventos de fullcalendar,* es solo para demostrar que horas son laborables y cuales no.

Para cambiar los colores, debes modificar el estilo `.fc-nonbusiness` para los dias no laborables

Lamentablemente, solo permite configurar el mismo patron para cada día de la semana que sea laborable.

Esto hay que agregar a la inicializacion del fullcalendar:

```
businessHours: {
  start: '10:00', // hora final
  end: '18:00', // hora inicial
  dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] // dias de semana, 0=Domingo
}
```

Ejemplo completo:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
      allDaySlot: false,
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      businessHours: {
        start: '10:00', // hora final
        end: '18:00', // hora inicial
        dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] // dias de semana, 0=Domingo
      },
      dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        $("#hora_seleccionada").html(date.format("MM/DD/YYYY, h:mm:ss"));
      }
  });
});
```

```css
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.0/fullcalendar.css";

.fc-nonbusiness {
  background: #90EE90  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>

<div id='hora_seleccionada'></div>
<hr>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: !!! Graciiias !! que más bien explicado !, es justo lo que quería ! muchas gracias de verdad

Comment: @LuisAlbertoAguileraClarke de nada colega